# Application will not release file (Possible Ghostscript Issue)

Tags: vb.net, ghostscript

I've been working on an application in which a portion of the code takes an EPS file, uses Ghostscript to convert the .eps file into a .jpg, and then links the .jpg to a PictureBox control. All of that seems to function fine, however, I'm attempting to have the application iterate through the "temp" folder where it stores the JPGs and delete all of them when the user clicks the "Exit" button on the form. The code for the file deletion is:

```
Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    frmFigureViewer.picMyJPEG.Image = Nothing
    'Clear folder contents if folder exists, ON Form Load
    If Directory.Exists("C:\Temp\StandaloneRPSTLViewer") Then
        For Each FilesToDelete In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Temp\StandaloneRPSTLViewer")
            System.IO.File.Delete(FilesToDelete)
        Next FilesToDelete
    End If
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

However, when debugging, I get an IOException error of: "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Temp\StandaloneRPSTLViewer\MXP56962.jpg' because it is being used by another process."

Below I've provided a second snippet of code where the problem likely exists. If necessary, and someone can point me in the right direction, I can upload the project files themselves if it will make it any easier.

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    frmMain.CurrentFigure = txtFigure.Text
    frmMain.MyTMCode = txtMyTMCode.Text
    frmFigureViewer.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    frmFigureViewer.Show()
    Dim ArrayUpperBound = FGCFigNo.Length
    FigureResult = Enumerable.Range(0, FGCFigNo.Length).Where(Function(f) FGCFigNo(f) = frmMain.CurrentFigure).ToArray
    frmFigureViewer.lblFGCfromFGCList.Text = FGCCode(FigureResult(0))
    frmFigureViewer.lblTOPCurrentFigureTitle.Text = FGCTitle(FigureResult(0))
    frmFigureViewer.lblTOPDisplayFigure.Text = FGCFigNo(FigureResult(0))
    frmFigureViewer.lblCurrentSheet.Text = FGCSheetNo(FigureResult(0))
    frmFigureViewer.lblFinalSheet.Text = FGCSheetNo(FigureResult(FigureResult.Length - 1))
    ArtResult = FGCArtID(FigureResult(frmFigureViewer.lblCurrentSheet.Text - 1))
    Dim JpgFilePath As String = "C:\Temp\StandaloneRPSTLViewer" + "\" + Mid(ArtResult, 1, ArtResult.Length - 4) + ".jpg"
    If File.Exists(JpgFilePath) Then
        GoTo OnlyDisplay
    End If
    Dim SourceFile As String = ""
    Dim DestinationFile As String = ""
    Dim EpsFilePath As String = ARTFOLDER + "\" + ArtResult
    If Not Directory.Exists("C:\Temp\StandaloneRPSTLViewer") Then 'If ArtFile staging folder does not exist, create it
        MkDir("C:\Temp\StandaloneRPSTLViewer")
    End If



    SourceFile = EpsFilePath
    DestinationFile = Mid(EpsFilePath, 1, Len(EpsFilePath) - 4) + " view.eps"
    FileCopy(SourceFile, DestinationFile)

    EpsFilePath = DestinationFile

    RunGS("-q", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dBATCH", "-dSAFER", "-sDEVICE=jpeg", _
      "-r600", "-dJPEGQ=100", "-dEPSCrop", "-dDownScaleFactor=0", "-dTextAlphaBits=4", "-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4", _
      "-sPAPERSIZE=letter", "-sOutputFile=" & JpgFilePath, EpsFilePath)
    Kill(EpsFilePath) 'KILLS THE "...view.eps" temporary file in the working folder.
OnlyDisplay:
    frmFigureViewer.picMyJPEG.Image = Image.FromFile(JpgFilePath)

    Fig036Result = Enumerable.Range(0, FIGURENO.Length).Where(Function(f) FIGURENO(f) = frmMain.CurrentFigure).ToArray 'Build subset array where FigureNo = Contents of Figure text box

    'BUILD DICTIONARY HERE'
    Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim DictionaryFigureNumber As Integer = 1
    Dim DictionarySortPosition As Integer = 1
    Do Until DictionaryFigureNumber = 1000
        Dim DictionaryFigureLetterASCII As Integer = 65
        dict.Add(DictionaryFigureNumber, DictionarySortPosition)
        DictionarySortPosition = DictionarySortPosition + 1
        Do Until DictionaryFigureLetterASCII = 91

            dict.Add(DictionaryFigureNumber & Chr(DictionaryFigureLetterASCII), DictionarySortPosition)
            DictionarySortPosition = DictionarySortPosition + 1
            DictionaryFigureLetterASCII = DictionaryFigureLetterASCII + 1
        Loop
        DictionaryFigureNumber = DictionaryFigureNumber + 1
    Loop
    'END OF DICTIONARY BUILDING

    Dim TempLength = Fig036Result.GetLength(0)
    TempLength = TempLength - 1
    Dim CurrentPlace As Integer
    CurrentPlace = 0
    Dim TempItemNo As String
    TempItemNo = ""
    Dim ArrayString As String
    ArrayString = ""
    Array.Clear(FinalDataArray, 0, FinalDataArray.Length)
    Array.Clear(FinalSortArray, 0, FinalSortArray.Length)
    'Build smaller subset array that contains concatonated strings ONLY for figure listed in textbox.
    Do Until CurrentPlace > TempLength

        Dim ArrayLocation As Integer = Fig036Result(CurrentPlace)
        If txtMyTMCode.Text = TMCODE(ArrayLocation) Then 'If statement to restrict text data in viewer to ONLY TM Code provided in the textbox
            TempItemNo = ITEMNO(ArrayLocation)
            TempSMR = SMnR(ArrayLocation)
            TempNSN = NSN(ArrayLocation)
            TempCAGE = CAGE(ArrayLocation)
            TempPartNum = PARTNUM(ArrayLocation)
            TempDescription = ITEMName(ArrayLocation)
            TempUOC = UOC(ArrayLocation)
            TempQTY = QTYFIG(ArrayLocation)
            TempIndvFGC = FGC(ArrayLocation)
            TempPLISN = PLISN(ArrayLocation)
            TempNHAPLISN = NHAPLISN(ArrayLocation)
            If TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "" Then
                TempTMIND = ""
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "1" Then
                TempTMIND = "*"
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "2" Then
                TempTMIND = "**"
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "3" Then
                TempTMIND = "***"
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "4" Then
                TempTMIND = "****"
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "5" Then
                TempTMIND = "*****"
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "6" Then
                TempTMIND = "******"
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "7" Then
                TempTMIND = "*******"
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "8" Then
                TempTMIND = "********"
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "9" Then
                TempTMIND = "*********"
            ElseIf TMIND(ArrayLocation) = "10" Then
                TempTMIND = "**********"
            End If

            Dim TempValue As String = ""
            dict.TryGetValue(TempItemNo, TempValue)
            ArrayString = TempItemNo + "|" + TempSMR + "|" + TempNSN + "|" + TempCAGE + "|" + TempPartNum + "|" + TempDescription + "|" + TempUOC + "|" + TempQTY + "|" + TempIndvFGC + "|" + TempPLISN + "|" + TempNHAPLISN + "|" + TempTMIND + "|"
            FinalDataArray(CurrentPlace) = ArrayString

            FinalSortArray(CurrentPlace) = TempValue


        End If
        CurrentPlace = CurrentPlace + 1
    Loop
    Dim DisplayArray(CurrentPlace - 1) As String
    Array.Clear(DisplayArray, 0, DisplayArray.Length)
    Dim DisplayArrayCounter As Integer
    DisplayArrayCounter = 0
    Array.Sort(FinalSortArray, FinalDataArray)
    For Each item In FinalDataArray
        If Not item Is Nothing Then
            DisplayArray(DisplayArrayCounter) = item
            DisplayArrayCounter = DisplayArrayCounter + 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim VertLocation As Integer = 5
    Dim Mypos As Integer
    Dim FillerItemNo As String = ""
    Dim FillerSMR As String = ""
    Dim FillerNSN As String = ""
    Dim FillerCage As String = ""
    Dim FillerPartNum As String = ""
    Dim FillerDesc As String = ""
    Dim FillerUOC As String = ""
    Dim FillerQTY As String = ""
    Dim FillerFGC As String = ""
    Dim FillerPLISN As String = ""
    Dim FillerNHAPLISN As String = ""
    Dim FillerTMIND As String = ""
    Dim FGCConflict As Boolean
    'Loop to split up Concatonated Strings, Create Textboxes, and Fill Them
    For i = 0 To (DisplayArray.Length - 1)
        If DisplayArray(i) = "" Then Exit For
        Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
        If Mypos > 0 Then
            FillerItemNo = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerSMR = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerNSN = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerCage = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerPartNum = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerDesc = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerUOC = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerQTY = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerFGC = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerPLISN = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerNHAPLISN = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
            Mypos = InStr(1, DisplayArray(i), "|", CompareMethod.Binary)
            FillerTMIND = Mid(DisplayArray(i), 1, Mypos - 1)
            DisplayArray(i) = Mid(DisplayArray(i), Mypos + 1, Len(DisplayArray(i)))
        End If



        Dim VertPT As Point = New Point(20, VertLocation)
        'ItemNo
        Dim MytxtBoxItemNo As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtBoxItemNo.Name = "txtItemNo" & i + 1
        MytxtBoxItemNo.Location = VertPT
        MytxtBoxItemNo.Text = FillerItemNo
        MytxtBoxItemNo.Visible = True
        MytxtBoxItemNo.Height = 20
        MytxtBoxItemNo.Width = 30
        MytxtBoxItemNo.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'SMRCode
        VertPT = New Point(80, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxSMR As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxSMR.Name = "txtSMR" & i + 1
        MytxtboxSMR.Location = VertPT
        MytxtboxSMR.Text = FillerSMR
        MytxtboxSMR.Visible = True
        MytxtboxSMR.Height = 20
        MytxtboxSMR.Width = 50
        MytxtboxSMR.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'NSN
        VertPT = New Point(170, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxNSN As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxNSN.Name = "txtNSN" & i + 1
        MytxtboxNSN.Location = VertPT
        If FillerNSN = "" Then
            FillerNSN = "NO NSN"
            MytxtboxNSN.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        End If
        MytxtboxNSN.Text = FillerNSN
        MytxtboxNSN.Visible = True
        MytxtboxNSN.Height = 20
        MytxtboxNSN.Width = 90
        MytxtboxNSN.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'CAGE
        VertPT = New Point(290, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxCAGE As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxCAGE.Name = "txtCage" & i + 1
        MytxtboxCAGE.Location = VertPT
        MytxtboxCAGE.Text = FillerCage
        MytxtboxCAGE.Visible = True
        MytxtboxCAGE.Height = 20
        MytxtboxCAGE.Width = 50
        MytxtboxCAGE.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'PART NUMBER
        VertPT = New Point(360, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxPartNum As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxPartNum.Name = "txtPartNum" & i + 1
        MytxtboxPartNum.Location = VertPT
        MytxtboxPartNum.Text = FillerPartNum
        MytxtboxPartNum.Visible = True
        MytxtboxPartNum.Height = 20
        MytxtboxPartNum.Width = 70
        MytxtboxPartNum.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'TM IND
        VertPT = New Point(455, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxTMIND As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxTMIND.Name = "txtTMIND" & i + 1
        MytxtboxTMIND.Location = VertPT
        MytxtboxTMIND.Text = FillerTMIND
        MytxtboxTMIND.AutoSize = False
        MytxtboxTMIND.Font = New Font(Me.Font.FontFamily, 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        MytxtboxTMIND.Visible = True
        MytxtboxTMIND.Height = 20
        MytxtboxTMIND.Width = 80
        MytxtboxTMIND.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'Description
        VertPT = New Point(554, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxDesc As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxDesc.Name = "txtDesc" & i + 1
        MytxtboxDesc.Location = VertPT
        MytxtboxDesc.Text = FillerDesc
        MytxtboxDesc.Visible = True
        MytxtboxDesc.Height = 20
        MytxtboxDesc.Width = 160
        MytxtboxDesc.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'UOC
        VertPT = New Point(740, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxUOC As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxUOC.Name = "txtUOC" & i + 1
        MytxtboxUOC.Location = VertPT
        MytxtboxUOC.Text = FillerUOC
        MytxtboxUOC.Visible = True
        MytxtboxUOC.Height = 20
        MytxtboxUOC.Width = 100
        MytxtboxUOC.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'QTY
        VertPT = New Point(870, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxQTY As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxQTY.Name = "txtQTY" & i + 1
        MytxtboxQTY.Location = VertPT
        MytxtboxQTY.Text = FillerQTY
        MytxtboxQTY.Visible = True
        MytxtboxQTY.Height = 20
        MytxtboxQTY.Width = 40
        MytxtboxQTY.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'Item's individual FGC
        VertPT = New Point(940, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxFGC As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxFGC.Name = "txtFGC" & i + 1
        MytxtboxFGC.Location = VertPT
        Dim FirstFourIndvFGC As String = Mid(FillerFGC, 1, 4)
        Dim FirstFourFGCList As String = frmFigureViewer.lblFGCfromFGCList.Text
        If Not FirstFourIndvFGC = FirstFourFGCList Then
            MytxtboxFGC.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            FGCConflict = True
        Else
            MytxtboxFGC.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
        End If
        MytxtboxFGC.Text = FillerFGC
        MytxtboxFGC.Visible = True
        MytxtboxFGC.Height = 20
        MytxtboxFGC.Width = 50
        MytxtboxFGC.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'PLISN
        VertPT = New Point(1050, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxPLISN As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxPLISN.Name = "txtPLISN" & i + 1
        MytxtboxPLISN.Location = VertPT
        MytxtboxPLISN.Text = FillerPLISN
        MytxtboxPLISN.Visible = True
        MytxtboxPLISN.Height = 20
        MytxtboxPLISN.Width = 50
        MytxtboxPLISN.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'NHA PLISN
        VertPT = New Point(1150, VertLocation)
        Dim MytxtboxNHAPLISN As TextBox = New TextBox
        MytxtboxNHAPLISN.Name = "txtNHAPLISN" & i + 1
        MytxtboxNHAPLISN.Location = VertPT
        MytxtboxNHAPLISN.Text = FillerNHAPLISN
        MytxtboxNHAPLISN.Visible = True
        MytxtboxNHAPLISN.Height = 20
        MytxtboxNHAPLISN.Width = 50
        MytxtboxNHAPLISN.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Horizontal
        'Add the controls and iterate VertLocation prior to starting the next RPSTL item
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtBoxItemNo)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxNSN)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxCAGE)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxTMIND)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxDesc)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxFGC)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxQTY)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxPartNum)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxUOC)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxSMR)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxPLISN)
        frmFigureViewer.p036text.Controls.Add(MytxtboxNHAPLISN)
        VertLocation = VertLocation + 30
    Next
    If FGCConflict = True Then
        If chkFGCConflict.Checked = True Then
            MsgBox("There is an FGC conflict within this figure. The ITEM FGC has been colored red for your convenience")
        End If
    End If
    JpgFilePath = ""
End Sub
```

UPDATE: The code for the RunGS subroutine is:

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

'--- Simple VB.Net wrapper for Ghostscript gsdll32.dll

'    (Tested using Visual Studio 2010 and Ghostscript 9.06)
Module GhostscriptDllLib
    Private Declare Function gsapi_new_instance Lib "gsdll32.dll" (ByRef instance As IntPtr, ByVal caller_handle As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Declare Function gsapi_set_stdio Lib "gsdll32.dll" (ByVal instance As IntPtr, ByVal gsdll_stdin As StdIOCallBack, ByVal gsdll_stdout As StdIOCallBack, ByVal gsdll_stderr As StdIOCallBack) As Integer
Private Declare Function gsapi_init_with_args Lib "gsdll32.dll" (ByVal instance As IntPtr, ByVal argc As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal argv() As String) As Integer
Private Declare Function gsapi_exit Lib "gsdll32.dll" (ByVal instance As IntPtr) As Integer
Private Declare Sub gsapi_delete_instance Lib "gsdll32.dll" (ByVal instance As IntPtr)

'--- Run Ghostscript with specified arguments
Public Function RunGS(ByVal ParamArray Args() As String) As Boolean

    Dim InstanceHndl As IntPtr
    Dim NumArgs As Integer
    Dim StdErrCallback As StdIOCallBack
    Dim StdInCallback As StdIOCallBack
    Dim StdOutCallback As StdIOCallBack

    NumArgs = Args.Count

    StdInCallback = AddressOf InOutErrCallBack
    StdOutCallback = AddressOf InOutErrCallBack
    StdErrCallback = AddressOf InOutErrCallBack

    '--- Shift arguments to begin at index 1 (Ghostscript requirement)

    ReDim Preserve Args(NumArgs)
    System.Array.Copy(Args, 0, Args, 1, NumArgs)

    '--- Start a new Ghostscript instance

    If gsapi_new_instance(InstanceHndl, 0) <> 0 Then
        Return False
        Exit Function
    End If

    '--- Set up dummy callbacks

    gsapi_set_stdio(InstanceHndl, StdInCallback, StdOutCallback, StdErrCallback)

    '--- Run Ghostscript using specified arguments

    gsapi_init_with_args(InstanceHndl, NumArgs + 1, Args)

    '--- Exit Ghostscript

    gsapi_exit(InstanceHndl)

    '--- Delete instance

    gsapi_delete_instance(InstanceHndl)

    Return True

End Function

'--- Delegate function for callbacks

Private Delegate Function StdIOCallBack(ByVal handle As IntPtr, _
  ByVal Strz As IntPtr, ByVal Bytes As Integer) As Integer

'--- Dummy callback for standard input, standard output, and errors

Private Function InOutErrCallBack(ByVal handle As IntPtr, _
  ByVal Strz As IntPtr, ByVal Bytes As Integer) As Integer

    Return 0

End Function
End Module
```

Comment: I don't know anything about GhostScript, but it looks like RunGS is a subroutine; are you disposing/closing everything that is being used in there?  I've had that error before when it was really a folder permissions problem, if I remember correctly, though it doesn't seem like that is it.  Also, sometimes "Kill" behaves differently than "File.Delete".  You could try both, see if there is a difference...

Comment: Also, as a side note, you can use:  TempTMIND = StrDup(CInt(Val(TMIND(ArrayLocation))), "*")  to set those asterisks.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not as familiar with GhostScript as I'd like to be either. I was able to implement it correctly after looking at some code, but that is the extent of my knowledge on it. I will post the code for the RunGS subroutine in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

So I did some further digging, and was able to come to the conclusion that the problem IS NOT with Ghostscript. It was that the PictureBox in my application was still holding the .jpg file in memory. Oddly enough, I assumed setting the PictureBox.src to "Nothing" would release the file, but that didn't work. After doing some various google searches, I was able to uncover a workaround here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/309482

> When you load a PictureBox control with a picture file, the Microsoft Visual Studio .NET or Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Integrated Development Environment (IDE) maintains a lock on the file. This occurs when you set the Image property of a PictureBox control to a file manually at design time, or when you use the FromFile method at run time.

RESOLUTION (for my application anyways):

```
Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
' Specify a valid picture file path on your computer.
fs = New System.IO.FileStream(JpgFilePath, 
 IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
frmFigureViewer.picMyJPEG.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
fs.Close()
```